# How to check whether vector b is in Col A?

Tags: matlab

How do I determine whether b∈Col A or b∉Col A in matlab? A being an m x n  matrix where m >= n, and b being a vector. Is there a built in function for this already, or would I need to create one? If b∈Col A, how would I go about determining whether matrix A has orthonormal columns/is orthogonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ismember` as explained in a previous answer.

```
// some sample data
A = [eye(3); zeros(3)];
v = [0; 1; 0; 0; 1; 0];

ismember(A', v', 'rows')
```

To check orthogonality, you could do the following

```
// A scalar initialised outside the for-loop. It stores sums of inner products.
dp = 0;

// Take the columns of A one by one and compute the inner product with all subsequent columns. If A is orthogonal, all the inner products have to be zero and, hence, their sum has to be zero.
for i = 1:size(A, 2)
    dp = dp + sum(A(:, i)'*A(:, i+1:end));
end

if (dp == 0)
    disp('The columns are orthogonal')
else
    disp('The columns are not orthogonal')
end
```

To have orthonormal columns, the norm of each column has to be 1, so:

```
// Check each column for unit length
M = mat2cell(A, size(A, 1), ones(size(A, 2), 1));

if find(cellfun(@(x)norm(x,2), M) ~= 1)
    disp('Columns are not of unit length')
else
    disp('Columns are of unit length')
end
```

Note that all these operations become simpler and faster if m=n (since you allow this case).

Comment: How about orthonormality of columns?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a matrix `A` that is `nxm` and a vector `b` that is `nx1`, and you want to see if b is a column in `A`.

You can do this by taking the transpose of both `A` and `b`, and then looking to see if the vector `b` is a member of `A`. This is the code:

```
member = ismember(A',b','rows');

Here is an example;

A =

     1     5
     2     2
     3     3
     4     4

b =

     1
     2
     3
     4


member = ismember(A',b','rows')

member =

     1
     0
```

So the first column of `A` and `b` are a match but the second column of `A` and `b` are not the same. If you want to check the orthogonality of the columns you can do this:

```
orthcheck = triu(A'*A);
```

if there are any zeros on the upper triangular matrix then the columns are orthogonal. The `A'*A` checks the dot product of all the columns and you only need the upper triagular part since the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Have an upvote. I want to see if anyone else has any other answers before choosing this as the correct one. Also, do you know anything about finding if matrix A has orthonormal columns?

Comment: "if there are any zeros on the upper triangular matrix then the columns are orthogonal" != true

Comment: @RDizzl3 What about `A = [eye(3); zeros(3)]; A(2, 1) = 1;`? The columns are not orthogonal, however `A'*A` has zeros in its upper triangular part.

Comment: How are the columns not orthogonal? All of their dot products are zero. In your solution you said take the column and compute the inner product with the other columns. Thats precisely what A'*A does. In the example you gave A(:,1) dot A(:,2) = 1*0+0*1+0*0+0*0+0*0 = 0 same with the other columns.

Comment: By definition of an orthogonal matrix A'*A=I. The example you provided satisfies this condition which means A is orthogonal and hence its columns.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of testing if `v` is a column of `A`:

```
any(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,v))) %// gives 1 if it is; 0 otherwise
```

To test if `A` is orthogonal:

```
product = A*A'; %'// I'm using ' in case you have complex numbers
product(1:size(A,1)+1:end) = 0; %// remove diagonal
all(product(:)==0) %// gives 1 if it is; 0 otherwise
```